# How to Execute the DataSet's Row Array Select Method in the case described?

Tags: sql, dataset

Kindly refer to code

```
DataRow[] rowToUpdate = database1DataSet1.Tables["purchase_invoice"].
                    Select(string.Format("PuchaseInvoiceId = '{0}' ",cbPurchaseInvoiceId.Text)); 

 error' Cannot perform '=' operation on System.Int32 and System.String.
```

Is There a Work Around.

Answer (score 1):

```
DataRow[] rowToUpdateUpdate = database1DataSet1.Tables["purchase_invoice"].                 
           if(cbPurchaseInvoiceId.Text.Trim()!="")
           Select(string.Format("PuchaseInvoiceId = '{0}' ",cbPurchaseInvoiceId.Text));
```

or

```
BindingSource bs = new BindingSource();
bs.DataSource = database1DataSet1.Tables["purchase_invoice"];
private void cbPurchaseInvoiceId_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if(cbPurchaseInvoiceId.Text .Trim ()!="")
    bs.Filter = string.Format("PuchaseInvoiceId = '{0}'", int.Parse    (txtempname.Text));
}
```